# Can not Update Columns by Sum, SQL Server, ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I can not UPDATE my SQL Server column by `SUM` and selecting the two different IDs in to tables?

Here is my code:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    txt_ID.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text;
}

string ObjektID = txt_ID.Text;

SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Summe As BigInt) As SummeXY, ItemObjektID FROM [Item] GROUP BY ItemObjektID");

cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE Objekt SET Summe = @Sum WHERE ObjektID = @ID";

try
{
    conn2.Open();
    cmd3.Connection = conn2;
    object result = cmd3.ExecuteScalar();

    cmd2.Connection = conn2;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ObjektID);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Sum", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(result);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

EDIT
This is my new Code but still does not work if I try it at SQL Query of the MS SQL Server it works?

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_ID.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text;
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ObjektID = txt_ID.Text;
        SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDataSource1"].ToString());  
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(); 
       cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE Objekt SET Summe = (SELECT SUM(Summe) as SummeXY FROM Item WHERE ItemObjektID = @ID GROUP BY ItemObjektID) WHERE ObjektID = @ID";  
         try
         {
             conn2.Open();
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ObjektID); 
             cmd2.Connection = conn2; 
             cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }

         catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
         {
             string msg = "Update Error:";  
             msg += ex.Message;
             throw new Exception(msg);
         }

         finally
         {
             conn2.Close();
        }
```

This is at aspx Site:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1"
    selectcommand="Select [ObjektID], [Name], [Beschreibung], [Summe], [PostenAls], [RangInBilanz] From [Objekt]"
updatecommand="UPDATE [Objekt] SET [Summe] = [SummeXY] (SELECT SUM([Summe]) as [SummeXY] FROM [Item] WHERE [ItemObjektID] = [@ID] GROUP BY [ItemObjektID]) WHERE [ObjektID] = [@ID]"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlDataSource1 %>"
    runat="server">
  </asp:sqldatasource>
```

I need help!

Comment: I don't think `object result = cmd3.ExecuteScalar();` is doing what you *think* it is. Why are you not doing this `UPDATE` in a single statement or, better yet, why are you storing aggregate data in the first place? If you need aggregate data, then use a `VIEW`.

Comment: Also you should really being using `Using` statements here; you don't even close your connection(s) in the above.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I do not get an Error. Closing con is in other part. Can you give me an example for a View?

Comment: The select statement in `cmd3` doesn't return a scalar, it returns a recordset. Also, `SUM(Summe As BigInt` should probably be `SUM(CAST(Summe As BigInt))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in my opinion, an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info); you should *not* be storing aggregated data in our tables. Doing so will only cause you to endlessly chase your tail as *every time* the table `Item` has a DML statement run against it you need to perform one against `Objekt` too.

Instead use a `VIEW` to calculate the aggregate values, and then if you need them, query that view. In it's *simplest* form, the `VIEW` will likely look something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.YourView AS
    
    SELECT I.ItemObjektID,
           SUM(CONVERT(bigint,I.Summe)) AS SummeXY
    FROM dbo.Item I
    GROUP BY I.ItemObjektID;
```

Of course, you may well want to `JOIN` to your table `Objekt` so that you can expose other columns from that table as well.

Comment: So I think this does not result the SUM: object result = cmd3.ExecuteScalar(); any suggestions how to get an result done?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comments, there's no need for 2 statements, 1 statement can be used to `UPDATE` the table, but like I state in the answer storing aggregates is rarely the correct answer.

Comment: So how to output into aspx Site the result of the SUM SELECT query?

Comment: Did you read [Patrick Hurst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18522514/patrick-hurst)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77600895/2029983)..?

Comment: Should I than just change the o into Objekt and try it?

Comment: My one and only try is to extract the right data from cmd3?

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by those comments. None of the answer reference `cmd3` because I still think this whole thing is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and you don't need an `UPDATE` at all. I can't answer questions about `cmd3` because my answer is that you don't do what you try to do; `cmd3` (and `cmd2`) is therefore irrelevant.

Comment: So in my opinion it can be that just either the ObjektID from the String txt_ID.text is not being read or just the UPDATE command is hole deffect, because if it would update without the data of cmd3, would if cmd3 is empty, the Objekt Column Summe would be empty after update! So I the the case is that the txt_ID.text does not match by upating!

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to state any more, `cmd3` is irrelvant to this answer so i've no idea why you keep cycling back to it. If you have a question about the `VIEW` I'm happy to answer it.

Comment: Maybe this SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Summe) As SummeXY, ItemObjektID FROM [Item] GROUP BY ItemObjektID"); has to be with an WHERE LIKE ObjektID?

Comment: But how to put the String: ObjektID into an Select statement?

Comment: Myabe that way: SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Summe) As SummeXY, ItemObjektID = OBjektX FROM [Item] GROUP BY ItemObjektID");

Comment: You need to `JOIN` to `Object` on your `JOIN` criteria, @SarsmasAhangari , whatever that is (it's not obvious from your queries).

Answer (score 0):

Consider performing your update as a single statement:

```
/* Some demo DDL/DML */
DECLARE @Objekt TABLE (ObjektID INT, Summe BIGINT);
INSERT INTO @Objekt (ObjektID) VALUES (1),(2),(3);

DECLARE @Item TABLE (ItemObjektID INT, Value INT);
INSERT INTO @Item (ItemObjektID, Value) VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(1,9),(3,1),(3,5);
```

```
DECLARE @ID INT = 2; /* This is not required when passing the param in from a Parameterized SqlCommand */

UPDATE o
   SET Summe = v.SummeXY
  FROM (
        SELECT i.ItemObjektID, SUM(CAST(i.Value AS BIGINT)) AS SummeXY
          FROM @Item i
         GROUP BY i.ItemObjektID 
       ) v
    INNER JOIN @Objekt o
      ON v.ItemObjektID = o.ObjektID
      AND o.ObjektID = @ID;
```

If we then select from the table:

```
SELECT *
  FROM @Objekt;
```

We can see it has been updated with the total for the **2** ID.

| ObjektID | Summe |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 |  |

As Thom explains in the other answer, this is possibly a sub-optimal strategy and it may be more effective to create a view with the totals, or perhaps a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16), instead (depending on the source and complexity of the actual calculation).

Comment: So the Update happens now, but not with the right ObjektID, so I have to adjust the SUM statement of SQL and put there the string ObjektID = txt_ID.Text; in like: ItemObjektID = ??? how?

Comment: You just need to pass the appropriate ID in as a parameter, which you were already doing. `cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = <your value>`